# how to resolve bleach==1.5.0 html5lib=0.9999999 on windows10

Tags: tensorflow, windows-10, pymc3

Hello I want to pip install pymc3 in tensorflow version 3.5 on windows

but it is not worked.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3
```

tensorflow-tensorboard 1.5.0 has requirement bleach==1.5.0, but you'll have bleach 2.1.2 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-tensorboard 1.5.0 has requirement html5lib==0.9999999, but you'll have html5lib 1.0.1 which is incompatible

please help me :(
[image: error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is clear from the error that there is a mismatch of the package versions. You have several options from here.

1. If you haven't installed `tensorboard` already, install tensorboard and see if the error is resolved: `pip install tensorboard`
2. If you have installed tensorboard already, uninstall tensorboard with: `pip uninstall tensorboard` and specify the version of tensorboard you want to install: `pip install tensorboard=1.5.1`. Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50454218/9859820) for more details

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by your screenshot, it is evident that the package **tensorflow-tensorboard** is not compatible with the latest version of **bleach** package. These are interdependent packages.

An easy solution, as suggested by your command prompt is to use an older version of **bleach** package.

- I tested the following command, which worked for me for installing **bleach 1.5.0**.
  `pip install -I bleach==1.5.0`
- I am using **pip version =** *10.0.1*.
  To check your current pip version, run the following command: `pip --version`
- After you're done with the installation, you can check the version of all your installed packages using
  `pip freeze`
- For more information about this compatibility issue, refer this [TensorFlow Article on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16424).
- You can do the same for **html5lib** as well, by following the exact steps above and changing the parameter.

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow-tensorboard is not compatible with the latest version of bleach package.
You have to install the following packages by

---

$ pip install numpy==1.13.0 --user

- You install the other with same
- Check the version of pip: 
   $ pip --version
- Update pip: $pip install --upgrade pip