# incompatible numpy and html5lib for tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, html5lib

`tensorflow 1.7.0 has requirement numpy>=1.13.3, but you'll have numpy 1.11.0 which is incompatible. 
tensorboard 1.7.0 has requirement html5lib==0.9999999, but you'll have html5lib 0.999 which is incompatible. 
tensorboard 1.7.0 has requirement numpy>=1.12.0, but you'll have numpy 1.11.0 which is incompatible.`

Please refer to this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6mmX.png)

Why are these messages showing up...even though I have the proper versions installed??I have upgraded and reinstalled them over and over. I also reinstalled pip and also tried easy install for pip. But the problem persists.

Could something be wrong with my OS installation? (Ubuntu 16.4)

These are some results I got by running 
`pip freeze`

```
tensorboard==1.8.0 
tensorflow==1.8.0 
numpy==1.14.3 
html5lib==0.9999999 
httplib2==0.9.1
```

Comment: Try to restart python kernel.

Answer (score 0):

The error showing up because

1. installing `lxml` require installing `numpy-1.11.0`
2. `tensorflow` (already installed) require `numpy>=1.13.3` (already installed)

To solve, you can:

1. downgrade tensorflow
2. try install a newer version of lxml.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to uninstall and reinstall compatible version

```
pip uninstall tensorflow-tensorboard
```

And then reinstall

```
pip install tensorflow-tensorboard==<your_version>
```

Ex. I did

```
pip install tensorflow-tensorboard==1.5.1
```